# React-router 2v vs React-router 3v - whats the difference?

Tags: react-router

So i am trying to go over from react router 2v to 3v, can anybody tell me the difference or where i can find more information about react router v3.

Comment: Check out their changelog https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: Thx Chris, i will check it out :)

Comment: that changelog link does not seem to work anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Router v3 removed the deprecated code that had warnings in v2. It is otherwise pretty much exactly the same.

v2 is no longer being developed and v3 is pretty much just being updated for bug fixes going forward. New features are only really being added to v4, which is a configuration-free rewrite.